# How can I know if a Javascript exception occurred in a PhoneGap application? (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, dom, cordova

How can I know if a Javascript exception occurred in a PhoneGap application?

I'm using HTC Desire Z and Android 2.2.

I don't see anything in logcat and jsconsole.com does not seem to support exception transporting.

Using console.log to trac every exception is bit hard. Is there a solution for this or is this just how it is with Phonegap?

EDIT: It seems to be possible to capture at least some of exceptions with some [really hacky wrappers](https://gist.github.com/963200). This some times can put you on the right track, but probably has some serious side effects and it won't certainly capture all the exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncaught exceptions should show up in logcat - at least the message and line number.

Otherwise you don't have many options. window.onerror does not work in Android AFAIK.

Comment: Even console.log doesn't seem to work on HTC devices. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847290/how-to-display-console-log-output-in-phonegap-app-using-eclipse-and-htc-desire/5849262#5849262 so maybe exceptions are disabled in similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

From a recent post from the PhoneGap blog:

> It’s a mobile browser! How am I
>   supposed to debug it! The answer is
>   that you aren’t. You are going to
>   debug your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
>   app in a desktop browser. The trick is
>   to remove any dependencies that you
>   have on PhoneGap before debugging.

http://www.phonegap.com/2011/05/18/debugging-phonegap-javascript/

Only if the desktop browser would work exactly like the mobile one...

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about logging the exceptions or about debugging them during development?

I'm not sure about the best way of logging them, but to debug them you can use [Weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre).

I just wrote about Weinre on another very similar question ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252262/172973 )

Basically it's a remote javascript debugger for phonegap. You can either setup your own Weinre server, or use the one at http://debug.phonegap.com/